# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket

I have Rails app on Digital Ocean (Ununtu 18.04 + nginx + passenger + Capistrano). I have chat functionality inside my app based on Action Cable. On my local everything works without problem, but on production i get next error: `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502.`
As i understand something wrong with Action Cable configuration. But everything done as in tutorials so i now really confused and don't know where i should looking for evil. Please help!
**production.rb** file

```
config.action_cable.url = '/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://example.com']
```

**cable.yml file**

```
production:
adapter: redis
url: redis://redis.exmaple.com:6379
```

**messages.coffee** file

```
jQuery(() ->
  App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create {channel: 'MessagesChannel', id: $('#conversation_id').val() },
    received: (data) ->
      jQuery('#new_message')[0].reset()
      jQuery('#chat').append data.message 
)
```

**messages_channel.rb** file

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "conversation_#{params[:id]}"
  end
end
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp** file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name example.com;
  root /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name myapp_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }
}
```

In nginx i have a lot of such errors:

```
2019/07/18 07:37:47 [error] 25500#25500: *9088 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 117.102.40.105, server: example, request: "GET /cable HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.q4FqjUT/agents.s/core:", host: "example.com"
```

Of course everywhere example.com is replaced with my real domain name.

Comment: Please post any relevant code as well as the error itself :)

Comment: And include any relevant messages from your nginx error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was in redis url in configuration. In each tutorial it write to use next code:

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://redis.example.com:6379
```

But looks that it is mistake and correct will be next code:

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379
```

So instead you domain should be used localhost. Hope, this will help somebody and will save a lot of time)